# When using .Split to populate a string array, I only get one entry. I need two

Tags: c#, arrays, split

Good morning Stack Mind!

I am working with C# in Unity3d.

I am pulling a string from the USGS rss atom feed that contains the Lat/Lon coordiates I need.  Once I have the string, I break it at the " " and put both entries into an array using string.Split.  Early in the script, I declare the array and populate it like so:

```
    string[] shakeup = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

I have confirmed that this works just fine, I can retrieve those entries as expected.

However, once I pull the string from my feed and break it up, I get an IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. error when I try to pull the new strings out of the array to convert them to floats.

The string I am pulling from the feed looks like this:

33.2903333 -115.695

The code I am using to split this string into two parts and use it to fill the array is this:

```
   void SplitIt()
    {
        //Read line, and split it by whitespace into an array of strings
        char delimiter = ' ';
        shakeup = Message.Split(' ');

        Debug.Log(shakeup[0]);
        Debug.Log("length is:" + shakeup.Length);
        Debug.Log(shakeup[1]);
```

The second Debug.Log (shakeup.Length) returns a 1.
That third Debug.Log is where I try to read back the second entry in the array, and that is where I get the error message.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.  I've googled and searched through both StackOverflow and the UnityAnswers forums, but haven't been able to untangle this exact issue.

I did consider using a List, but since the array is only ever two coordinates, this seemed a simpler solution with slightly less overhead (until I spent 12 hours trying to debug it, of course).

EDIT:
It may be an issue with the string I am getting.  It passes through as a string just fine, I can print it to console, Unity treats it like any other string.  I'm pulling it from here:

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.atom
34.2495 -118.5568333

Second point, The first part of the string goes into the array just fine.  If I call the entry "shakeup[0]" I get "34.2495" as expected.  It's the second part of the string that is getting eaten.

Comment: "*shakeup.Length returns a 1*" well that's because there is only one item, not that `1` is the highest index of the array. Chances are you are splitting a string with no spaces in it

Comment: What do you get if you do `Debug.Log(Message.IndexOf(" "));`?

Comment: Zero based index ;)

Comment: seems like tab delimited `.Split('\t')`

Comment: If I change the character (for example I use "-" as my split point).  I still get the same result.

Comment: Note that if you are uncertain what the delimiter is, then `Message.Split(null);` will split on _any_ whitespace.

Comment: Alfie, Yep, there is only one entry.  But there should be two (0, 1), if the split worked properly, right?  When I retrieve entry 0, it shows up as it should.  When I retrieve entry 1, I get the error.

Comment: Is this the _only_ string you're trying to split or is this in a loop?  If `shakeup.Length` is 1 then there is only 1 entry and you shouldn't call `shakeup[1]`.

Comment: juharr - adding that returns a -1

Comment: What are the contents of `Message` before the split? I mean, I can see what you are expecting to be operating on, but are you sure that's the data you are getting in exactly? Do a `Debug.Log(Message);` before the split.

Comment: D Stanley - this is the only string.  I pull it once, then break it into two parts (in theory) so I can convert them to doubles.

Comment: Abion - The "33.2903333 -115.695" I posted is pulled directly from a Debug.Log(Message).

Comment: Is it from this method? Did you remove it from the code in your post for compactness' sake? I'm just trying to guess as to what could be wrong, as it seems like as it stands it should be working, but not getting the correct input at the time of the split would explain it. (Also, if you want to reply to a specific person, use the @ character, i.e. @KimberlyUnger )

Comment: @Abion47 Thanks :) I wan't sure if the @ as a standard had carried over from other sites.

Comment: @Abion47   I called the Debug.Log(Message) just before attempting the split, so the information *should* be there.  The first number enters the array just fine, I can retrieve it as expected.  It's the second one that is getting lost.

Comment: Examine the message data .ToCharArray() and see what the seperation character really is.  The most likely explanation is that they are not seperated by that you thin they are.  `Split()` is not likely broke

Comment: @Plutonix Got it, I'll run that through and let you know if it worked.

Comment: (its a diagnostic step, not a remedy)

Comment: Seems like the character pulled from the coordinates (between the `georss:point` tags) has the value 32, which is indeed a space character...

Comment: @Plutonix yeah :) I know it's a debug.  It returns a " " as far as I can tell. I used this code. and in the list of characters there is a blank space.                                                                                   void CheckChr()
        {
            char[] array = Message.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                char letter = array[i];

                Debug.Log("Letter: ");
                Debug.Log(letter);
                
            }

Comment: Running the code through DotNetFiddle produces results as should be expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhrAyo (The coordinates are retrieved via Regex so as to simplify the test.)

Comment: @Abbion47 Thanks for cross-checking!  If I just declare a string (Message = ("this is not a fish"); then .Split seems to work just fine.  No matter what character I choose on the string I pull from that feed (3, 1, -. " ", etc) it refuses to split properly, so it must be something in between the feed and the string.

Comment: @Abion47 YOU NAILED IT!  I was using "Message" on a loop elsewhere to populate a UI entry, so when it updated, it was interrupting this action.  I moved the execution of the .Split to a different segment of the code so they don't interfere and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for helping me debug this one!

As it turns out, the Message string was being updated in another script.  That update was interfering with the execution of .Split.   I was able to solve this by moving .Split to a different area of the script.

Comment: You may mark your own answer as the correct answer for others to see that your issue has been resolved :)

Comment: I will :)  Because I am a Stack Overflow rookie it's making me wait a few days :D